# Expiring Products

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

What i am looking to do is to be able to create products with an expire date.

When the current date matches the expire date in the database it will change the boolean field on that product. (Boolean is visible/hidden).

This will also send out an email to say that the product has expired.

This needs to happen automatically every day or twice a day.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a cron job:

1. Run a job every (hour|day|whatever) that selects form the product table where expiry_date > current date  (you didn't say which db you are using so syntax will vary)
2. For each result, send an email, set the flag to true and commit the update.

Comment: See this related ruby/cron library:  https://github.com/javan/whenever

Comment: Hi Dave is what i want to do 100% db is Mysql

Comment: My proposed solution should work then.